# Javascript Import from Relative URL (Browser)

Tags: javascript, browser, import

Is there a way to import a Javascript file from a URL (relative) in the browser from Javascript code?

I know you can import a Javascript file from HTML but I don't want to do that.

I would expect something like this:

```js
import { functionName } from "/static/javascript/fileName";

functionName();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, relative URLs are absolutely fine. A couple of things to note:

- Like all other relative URLs in the browser environment, they're resolved **client-side**.
- Your `import` is syntactically correct, but you probably meant to have `.js` on there, because browsers do not add file extensions for you.

If your `import` were in a file at `https://example.com/something/somefile.js`, your `import` would be telling the browser to import from `https://example.com/static/javascript/fileName`.

Guessing a bit from the name of your path, you probably wanted:

```
import { functionName } from "./fileName.js";
```

That tells the browser to import from `fileName.js` on the same path as the JavaScript file the `import` occurs in. So if the `import` were in `https://example.com/something/somefile.js`, the browser would look for `https://example.com/something/fileName.js`.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that when including the Javascript file ('somefile.js' in this case) in the HTML, you must specify `type='module'`.