# How do you link external JS files to HTML files?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to link a function from one JS file to another and then link the main JS file to my HTML file. I have browsed stack overflow and used Phind, but have still not been successful.

**Here is my error:**
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/Users net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

**
Here is the HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Create an account!</h1>
    <script type="module" src ='everything.js'></script>

    <form>
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
        <label for="fname">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname"><br><br>
        <label for="lname">Gender:</label>
        <input type="text" id="gender" name="gender"><br><br>
        <label for="fname">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="address"><br><br>
        <label for="lname">Add profile image:</label>
        <input type="text" id="pimage" name="pimage"><br><br>
        <input type = "button" id="caccount" name="createaccount" onclick="createAccount()"       value="create account">
        <label for ="caccount">
      </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the JS:**

```
import { User } from './Users';

let accounts = [];
let firstName;
let userName;
let gender;
let address;

export function createAccount(){
    alert("Account created!");
    document.getElementById("fname").value = firstName;
    document.getElementById("uname").value = userName;
    document.getElementById("gender").value = gender;
    document.getElementById("address").value = address;
    // document.getElementById("fname").value = profileImage;

    const newUser = new User(firstName, userName, gender, address);

    accounts.push(newUser);
}


console.log(accounts);
```

**I've tried:**

- using require instead of import
- updating the package.json to understand that I am using modules
- putting all the code in one file to avoid having to import from other JS files
- using an event listener

I am working on localhost. I am expecting the function to run and push a user onto the array on button click and log the populated array to the console.

Comment: Does `Users` exist in your directory?  Is it actually `Users.js`?

Comment: `updating the package.json` is irrelevant, this is a *web page* ... nothing you've shown indicates `node.js` is at all relevant

Comment: Does the question ["Javascript Import from Relative URL (Browser)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70640698/5217142) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640749/5217142) solve your issue?

Comment: Sadly it does not. I have the module src tag, I have the correct syntax for the the script line and it still does not recognize the function in the JS file. Ive also triple checked spelling and other small syntactical items.

Comment: So there's  a  JavaScript file called `Users` in the same directory as `everything.js`? Is there a reason for using  uppper case :"U" at the start of the filename and not providing it with a file extension of any kind?

Comment: Note that [HTTP 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) error messages originate on the server and indicate  the requested resource could not be found to send as a response. It does not relate to the correctness or not of JS file content sent to the front end by the server. If you need further help, please include (in the _question_) the routing of you nodejs app for the `get` request that you expect should return the user file.